# Importing openzeppelin in hardhat contracts error

Tags: ethereum, solidity, openzeppelin, hardhat

I am attempting to deploy a contract with some @openzeppelin/contracts imports.

The Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract EthOrb is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
//code
}
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "eth-orb-contracts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "smart contracts for dapps",
  "main": "hardhat.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "hardhat": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

The @openzeppelin/contracts is in my node_modules and I ran an npm I to install again.

expected outcome: imports deps successfully.

actual outcome:
error msg in terminal:

```
Compiling 14 files with 0.8.0
ParserError: Source "node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
 --> contracts/EthOrb.sol:5:1:
  |
5 | import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


ParserError: Source "node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
 --> contracts/EthOrb.sol:6:1:
  |
6 | import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


ParserError: Source "node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
 --> contracts/EthOrb.sol:7:1:
  |
7 | import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


Error HH600: Compilation failed
```

Edit:
Removing the '../node_modules' doesnt solve this either.

This gives lint errors:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```

And the error is:

```
Compiling 14 files with 0.8.0
ParserError: Source "node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
 --> contracts/EthOrb.sol:5:1:
  |
5 | import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


ParserError: Source "node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
 --> contracts/EthOrb.sol:6:1:
  |
6 | import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


ParserError: Source "node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
 --> contracts/EthOrb.sol:7:1:
  |
7 | import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


Error HH600: Compilation failed
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem and solved it by moving the entire "@openzeppelin/contracts" to the root of where the contract is written.

Example:
I have a folder Contracts and inside of it I have the @openzeppelin folder and the MyContract.sol file.
Then I just imported the contract like this:

import "./@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

Comment: This is a solution, but creating symlinks seems like extra steps, is there really no other way?

Comment: You do not create symlinks, you copy the folder of the contracts from the node_modules folder (they are files) to the root folder of the project.

Comment: Yeah but then `npm update` are no more managed, which I don't like. In the end copying and symlinking produces the same result.

Comment: That's true, this is just a temporary workaround that I found, hopefully they'll fix this in the future to keep it updated

Comment: Yes no thats an okay workaround just wondered whether someone knows something new or something. I tried to find a config variable to specify the `include_directories` where the compiler should look for `*.sol`, but haven't found anything. That would probably be a clean fix. VSCode does it in that way for example.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little bit difference between importing the code in solidity and hardhat code

Solidity code

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";
```

hardhat code

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```

Change the path according to your requirement.
**You can see the contracts path in artificats/openzepeppelin/ contracts. So import accordingly.**

Answer (score 0):

open node_modules dir in your project folder and search for "@openzepplin" under that find "contracts" if not found run this command

npm install @openzeppelin/contracts

then you will see it resolved and not showing an error.

Answer (score -1):

Following my comment above:
I found a slightly better fix, you can create a symlink in your root directory where root is:

```
root
   contracts
   tests
   artifacts 
   ...
   ln -s node_modules/@openzeppelin
```

if you create there a symlink openzeppelin will get updated and also you can now access without prepending it as a relative directory, which I like more.
So you can now go with `import '@openzeppelin/...'`, hope this helps someone.